# Django custom login, how can I add ForeignKey to REQUIRED_FILED

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I tried to create a custom login for Django, and one of the fields in

**User(AbstractBaseUser)**

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser): 
    user_email      = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email right here', max_length=70, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    password        = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password_salt   = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    create_date     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    role            = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    info            = models.ForeignKey(PersonalInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'user_email' #username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [info.lastname, info.firstname] #email and pass is required by defaut

    object          = UserManager()

    def __str__(self): 
        """
        Return user email 
        """
        return self.user_email

    def get_email(self): 
        """
        Return user email 
        """
        return self.user_email
    
    def get_info(self): 
        """
        return user info
        """
        return self.info
```

I have my `PersonalInfo` model like this:

```py
class PersonalInfo(models.Model): 
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    work_email   = models.EmailField(verbose_name=' email', blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    lastname    = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='Last name', verbose_name="Last name")
    firstname   = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='First name', verbose_name="First name")
    address     = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    work_phone  = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, db_column='Work Phone', unique=True)
    cell_phone  = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, db_column='Cell Phone', unique=True)
    home_phone  = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, db_column='Home Phone', unique=True)
    note        = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'PersonalInfo'


    def __str__(self): 
        """
        return lastname and firstname
        """
        return self.firstname + ' , '+ self.lastname
```

and I got this ERROR:

```py
REQUIRED_FIELDS = [info.lastname, info.firstname]
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'lastname'
```

How can I include `info.lastname` and `info.firstname` in `REQUIRED_FIELDS`?

Comment: What are the views and forms that you're using? Is there a particular library you're using as well? There's not enough information in your question to answer it as is.

Comment: they are required field by default. untill you add null=True, blank=True in first_name and last_name in PersonalInfo